# regular expression in Perl to excluded patterns but include pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I want to have a regex pattern to match a line:
1.this line must contain the word "s200"
2. the end of the string cannot be "sping","js","json","css"

Here is a monster I got,which doesn't work

`(?=^.*$(?<!sping)(?<!js)(?<!css)(?<!json))(?=s200)`

I am new to regex, any help would be aapreciated!

Comment: It _must_ be regex?

Comment: `(?s)^(?!sping$)(?!js$)(?!css$)(?!json$)(?=s200)`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your regex doesn't match anything because you only have lookarounds in your regex.

```
?=           # look ahead for match
?<!          # negative look behind
```

In other words, you're not matching anything, with your regex you're looking for a `position` in a string.

explanation:

```
(?=              # pos. lookahead
 ^.*$            # read anything
                 # and AFTER reading everything, check
 (?<!sping)      # if you have NOT read sping
 (?<!js)         # if you have NOT read js
 (?<!css)        # if you have NOT read css
 (?<!json)       # if you have NOT read json
)
(?=s200)         # from this position, check if there's "s200" ahead.
```

Conclusion: your regex will never ever comply with your requirements.

You could solve this with just one regex, for example with:

```
(.*)s200(.*)$(?<!css|js|json|sping)
```

which says

```
.*                       # read anything
s200                     # read s200
.*                       # read anything
$                        # match the end of the string
(?<!css|js|json|sping)   # negative lookbehind: 
                         # if you have read css,js,json or sping, fail
```

You could do this simple in two steps:

- first check if string contains s200 with `/s200/`
- check if string doesn't end with sping, js, json or json with `/css|js(on)?|sping$/`

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this as `perl`, so here's a `perl` solution:

```
$_ = $stringToTest;
if (/s200/) {
    # We now know that the string contains "s200"
    if (/sping|json|js|css$/) {
        # We now know it end with one of sping,json,js or css
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why the effort of OP doesn't work, because that's the question.